# Chrome Drag and Drop not working for Canvas Element with Selenium Action Classes

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automation

I am using Selenium 2.53.1, Selenium Support Class 2.53.1 and Chrome Version  59.0.3071.115 and Chrome Driver 2.30. It seems like drag and drop operation is not working on Chrome but working on firefox. It was working till yesterday but suddenly it stopped working, I checked if some upgrade has broken its working but it doesn't appear like it. Following is my code:

```
 public void DragAndDrop(IWebDriver driver, By source, By destination, int sourceX, int sourceY, int destinationX, int destinationY)
        {
            try
            {
                IWebElement sourceElement = FindElement(driver, source);
                IWebElement destinationElement = FindElement(driver, destination);
                Actions Actions = new Actions(driver);
                Actions.MoveToElement(sourceElement, sourceX, sourceY).ClickAndHold().Build().Perform();
                Actions.MoveByOffset(5, 0);
                Actions.MoveToElement(destinationElement, destinationX, destinationY).Release().Build().Perform();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check sourceX and sourceY if they are correct or not.

If they are correct, use dragAndDropBy(sources, xInteger, yInteger).

Comment: Source X and Y are correct that's why it is working in Firefox and I am dragging the element from one canvas(HTML5 element) to another canvas so I cannot use this.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your case, my scripts stopped working overnight. 
Downgrading Chromedriver worked as a temporary solution.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answer, you need to use comments for that, get 50 rep quick, by contributing to the community.

Comment: Which chrome driver did you downgrade to?